# In Collection Interface method boolean equals(Object obj) does any Object obj qualifies as parameter or only Collection c qualifies as parameter?

Tags: java, object, collections, parameters

I have the following code -

```
Collection collection1 = new ArrayList();
collection1.add(new Integer(1));

Collection collection2 = new ArrayList();
collection2.add(new Integer(1));

Integer integer = new Integer(1);

System.out.println(collection1.equals(collection2));
System.out.println(collection1.equals(integer));
```

Output -

```
true
false
```

The result is as expected. But then shouldn't the Collection Interface method be - `boolean equals(Collection c)`?

But, instead it is `boolean equals(Object obj)`

So how can it be that a non Collection Object can be successfully passed as parameter to get boolean output true?

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/12323248)

Comment: No, I mean what is the necessity of the Collection Interface method being `boolean equals(Object obj)` when clearly the only way it works is `boolean equals(Collection c)`

Comment: That's why I am asking for an example where an Object which is not Collection when passed as parameter can give boolean return true

Comment: You are not getting my point at all. Please read the code I have provided kindly

Comment: See, in the Collection Interface of java there is a method - `boolean equals(Object obj)` If we have two collections - collection1 and collection2 having same elements then we can use `collection1.equals(collection2)` to get boolean output true. But I can't think of an example when we have an `Object obj` where `obj` is not collection, but still `collection.equals(object)` will return true

Comment: My question is why the java developers did not declare the method as `boolean equals(Collection c)` instead? Because every Collection is Object but not every Object is Collection

Comment: `Object o = collection1, p = collection2;` Now to `o.equals(p)`… Besides that, as said by akuzminykh, don’t use raw types. Further, don’t use `new Integer(1)`, it’s unnecessary and deprecated since Java 9. Just `add(1)` and `Integer integer = 1;` do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals method is inherited from Object and you cannot change it's signature. The implementations of the equals method will take care of verifying if the object passed is actually an instance of Collection for example.
Edit:
Changing the signature of equals method will result in a class with two equals method, which is  unnecessary.

Comment: But then why not define the method as boolean equals(Collection c) when clearly an object which is not collection will never be able to return true?

Comment: Because all classes, including Collection inherits Object. This means it inherits equals method and if you try to override it with Collection instead of Object it will be overloading, so you will end up with two equals method.

Comment: But the question is why not make the method boolean equals(Collection c) instead? Every Collection is Object but not every Object is Collection.

Comment: Why to create two methods with exactly the same functionality? Since you are forced to inherit the one from object that one should be used. The same is used also in hashmap for example, if you don't implement it your object can't be used as key.

Comment: Since Collections are Objects as well any property of Object applies for Collection as well. So we don't require two separate methods. Only `boolean equals(Collection c)` is sufficient

Comment: You seem not to understand inheritance. The collection overrides the method from Object so it must stick to the signature given in Object.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I got my answer. Please consider putting this as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I added the details in my  answer.

Comment: Some classes do offer both `equals` methods. But for an interface, this was not feasible.